# Python Selenium Actionchains reset doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i'm trying to build a bot for a friend of mine using Selenium.
In order to do that I need to use Selenium's Actionchains few times with different actions in it
but the reset command doesn't work and the new commands just add on to the previous commands

please help me to solve that

```
import time
import pause
from datetime import datetime
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
import webbrowser
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import *

paragraph = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tps_slideContainer_17955"]/div/h3').text
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="post-title-0"]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
actions.send_keys(subtitle)
actions.perform()
actions.reset_actions()
actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL)
actions.key_down(Keys.ALT)
actions.send_keys('y')
actions.key_up(Keys.CONTROL)
actions.key_up(Keys.ALT)
actions.perform()
actions.reset_actions()
actions.send_keys(paragraph)
actions.perform()
actions.reset_actions()
```

Comment: Upload the whole code and the platform that you want to automate in order for us to practise on that. Thanks

Comment: There was a bug in selenium sometime last year where `.reset_actions()` did not work. Make sure you are on an up to date version. Also, please consider adding a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking.